# I need to join 2 dataframes based on rlike in scala spark

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, join

I have 2 dataframes, I need to join them based on rlike. The idea here is to get only data which matches in df2.Below is the sample.

```
df1->
football is a game
kids play games

df2->
%football%
%basketball%

output->

football is a game.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the code being in python and not in Scala. The transformations are the same in both languages :)

Firstly, create the sample dataframes:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> 
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
>>> 
>>> sentences = spark.createDataFrame(
>>>     [["football is a game"],
>>>      ["kids play games"],
>>>      ["I dont like basketball"]],
>>>     schema=["sentence"]
>>> )
>>> 
>>> likes = spark.createDataFrame(
>>>     [["%football%"],
>>>      ["%basketball%"]],
>>>     schema=["like"]
>>> )
>>> 
>>> sentences.show()
+-----------------------+
|sentence               |
+-----------------------+
|football is a game     |
|kids play games        |
|I dont like basketball |
+-----------------------+
>>> likes.show()
+------------+
|        like|
+------------+
|  %football%|
|%basketball%|
+------------+
```

### Option 1: joining the two dataframes

Do a join and use as join expression your condition:

```py
>>> sentences.join(likes, F.expr("sentence LIKE like")).show()
+-----------------------+------------+
|sentence               |like        |
+-----------------------+------------+
|football is a game     |%football%  |
|I dont like basketball |%basketball%|
+-----------------------+------------+
```

> I guess the `likes` dataframe is probably not very big, so doing a [broadcast](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.broadcast.html?highlight=broadcast#pyspark.sql.functions.broadcast) join makes sense. It'd be something like this: `sentences.join(F.broadcast(likes), F.expr("sentence LIKE like"))`.

### Option 2: generate one LIKE expression

This way you generate a huge like expression and then filter (you avoid the join, which yields virtually no gain if you can broadcast the `likes` dataframe). This way you will have only one row per sentence matched, but you won't know which like expression produced the match.

```py
>>> likes_list = [row.like for row in likes.collect()]
>>> like_expr = "' OR sentence LIKE '".join(likes_list)
>>> like_expr = "sentence LIKE '" + like_expr + "'"
>>> like_expr
'sentence LIKE '%football%' OR sentence LIKE '%basketball%''
>>> sentences.filter(like_expr).show()
+-----------------------+
|sentence               |
+-----------------------+
|football is a game     |
|I dont like basketball |
+-----------------------+
```

Comment: The first option results in cross join, I have millions of records on left dataframe and few hundreds on the right

Comment: Then put the filter expression as a join expression: `sentences.join(likes, F.expr("sentence LIKE like")).show()`.  In deed, the filter after coss join is a big mistake :(